# SSIS/SSRS to SAS

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssis, sas, proc

We have a migration task, which require to migrate ~30GB data from SQL server to SAS grid. We already have close to 50 reports using SSIS/SSRS and those need to move entirely to SAS grid. I am more familiar with SAS and haven't worked on SSIS/SSRS stuff.

How do I go about moving the process to SAS?
I know I can use Passthrough in SAS to call the SSIS/SSRS stuff from Proc SQL, but since they want everything needs to be coded in SAS, I am wondering if there is an easy way.

Is there a tool that can convert the SQL code and writes Proc sql code in SAS?

Thanks!
Park

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to view the queries behind the SSIS jobs (run the report, then view the details behind it).  Once you have the queries, copy/paste the SQL code into a SAS SQL passthrough statement.  The table returned should give the same results as the report.  It's then up to you to format the output as desired.

Comment: SSIS could be doing tons of procedural stuff. That won't be so easy to replicate as copying SQL statements.

Comment: Possibly... we had to go through this process at my current work and it was as simple as what I stated above.  I guess it may differ depending on the implementation, but it may help the OP.

Comment: True. It's a great tip for a starting point. However, if SSIS is involved prior to SSRS, there is about a 0% chance that it's a simple query. Simple queries usually just show up in SSRS without an SSIS pipeline being involved.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for your pointers. I will see how that goes.

Comment: Since the data is migrated to SAS, SQL passthrough should not be necessary. They would have to convert the SQL to Proc SQL, so it might not be so easy.